# Override test in spock

Tags: groovy, spock

I have a test written in a base class

```
abstract class BaseEdgeSpec extends Specification {
    Edge edge
    Edge switched
    abstract def 'equals with both vertices switched'()
}
```

And two classes I want to implement this test. One for normal edges

```
class EdgeTestSpec extends BaseEdgeSpec {
    def setup() {
        edge = new Edge(one:'step1', two:'step2')
        switched = new Edge(one: 'step2', two: 'step1')
    }
    @Override
    def 'equals with both vertices switched'() {
        expect:
        edge == switched
    }
}
```

And one for directed edges

```
public class DirectedEdgeSpec extends BaseEdgeSpec {
    def setup() {
        edge = new DirectedEdge(one:'step1', two:'step2')
        switched = new DirectedEdge(one:'step2', two:'step1')
    }
    @Override
    def 'equals with both vertices switched'() {
        expect:
        edge != switched
    }
}
```

When I run the tests I get these errors

```
/etc/user/john/projects/graph-dsl/src/test/groovy/nondsl/edges/DirectedEdgeSpec.groovy: 6: Can't have an abstract method in a non-abstract class. The class 'nondsl.edges.DirectedEdgeSpec' must be declared abstract or the method 'java.lang.Object equals with both vertices switched()' must be implemented.
 @ line 6, column 1.
   public class DirectedEdgeSpec extends BaseEdgeSpec {
   ^
/etc/user/john/projects/graph-dsl/src/test/groovy/nondsl/edges/DirectedEdgeSpec.groovy: 16: Method '$spock_feature_1_0' from class 'nondsl.edges.DirectedEdgeSpec' does not override method from its superclass or interfaces but is annotated with @Override.
 @ line 16, column 5.
       @Override
       ^
/etc/user/john/projects/graph-dsl/src/test/groovy/nondsl/edges/EdgeTestSpec.groovy: 16: Method '$spock_feature_1_0' from class 'nondsl.edges.EdgeTestSpec' does not override method from its superclass or interfaces but is annotated with @Override.
 @ line 16, column 5.
       @Override
       ^
3 errors
```

How can I override these tests correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably cannot. Spock transforms all "feature methods" (your tests) such that they end up being called `$spock_feature_%d_%d` in the byte code. Hence the error message *"Method '$spock_feature_1_0' [...] does not override method from its superclass or interfaces but is annotated with @Override."*

[`org.spockframework.compiler.SpecParser.isFeatureMethod(MethodNode)`](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/spock-1.1/spock-core/src/main/java/org/spockframework/compiler/SpecParser.java#L149)
[`org.spockframework.compiler.SpecRewriter.createInternalName(FeatureMethod)`](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/spock-1.1/spock-core/src/main/java/org/spockframework/compiler/SpecRewriter.java#L260)

As an alternative to overriding, you can still extract test logic to a superclass method and call that from within a test in the subclass.